# Activity crashes when using animated gif and movie (Android)

Tags: android, gif, movie, animated

My code right now downloads an animated gif from a website, and since, as far as I know, webview and imageview doesn't support animated gifs and using BufferedInputStream and Movie.decodeStream along with a custom View to render it (this code runs in a seperate thread)
I have tested the code on the android emulator (1.6, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3), Xperia X8 with 2.1, ViewSonic viewpad with 2.2 and Galaxy S with 2.3.3 and the activity only crashes on the Galaxy S (after like 1 minute). On the other devices it's working just fine.
I've tried debugging the app on the Galaxy S and I get this message just before it crashes:

```
11-17 13:37:18.152: ERROR/(1161): Wink AGIF pDecInfo is Null or not avail
```

That's all I get when debugging :(

I've tried changing my code back and forth but I can't get it working. Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also have some problems with Samsung devices. I was told that Samsung heavily modifies original Android source code so they seem to introduce many bugs.